# R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) | Using package dplyr_1.0.0 | Unable to perform summarise() function

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to perform the basic Summarise() function but getting the same error again and again!

I have a large number of csv files having 4 columns. I am reading them into R using lapply and rbinding them. Next I need to see the number of complete observations present for each ID.

Error:

```
 *Problem with `summarise()` input `complete_cases`.
    x unused argument (Date)
    i Input `complete_cases` is `n(Date)`.
    i The error occured in group 1: ID = 1.*
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
merged <-do.call(rbind,lapply(list.files(),read.csv))
merged <- as.data.frame(merged)
remove_na <- merged[complete.cases(merged),]
new_data <- remove_na %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(complete_cases = n(Date))
```

[Here is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaCQu.jpg)

Comment: Hi Sparsh, dataset should be shared using `dput` (and maybe Pastebin if too long), not as an image.

Comment: @DanChaltiel I'll keep that in mind! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not coming from `summarise` but from `n`.

If you look at the help `?n`, you will see that `n` is used without any argument, like this:

```
new_data_count <- remove_na %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(complete_cases = n())
```

This will count the number of rows for each `ID` group and is independent from the `Date` column. You could also use the shortcut function `count`:

```
new_data_count <- remove_na %>% count(ID)
```

If you want to count the different `Date` values, you might want to use `n_distinct`:

```
new_data_count_dates <- remove_na %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(complete_cases = n_distinct(Date))
```

Of note, you could have written your code with `purrr::map`, which has better functions than `_apply` as you can specify the return type with the suffix. This could look like this:

```
library(purrr)
remove_na = map_dfr(list.files(), read.csv) %>% na.omit()
```

Here, `map_dfr` returns a data.frame with binding rows, but you could have used `map_dfc` which returns a data.frame with binding columns.

Comment: @SparshGoyal Glad I helped, did this solve your problem?